Alerta al faltar los caracteres permitidos en input
Tengo el siguiente código que deseo modificar, me gustaría lo siguiente: el campo permite hasta 30 caracteres máximos y si a este se le ingresa, por ejemplo 10 caracteres, salte una alerta indicándolo.


//Creamos la Funcion
function kotoba() {
  $("#result").val($("#write").val().length + " Caracteres"); //Detectamos los Caracteres del Input
  $("#result").addClass('mui--is-not-empty'); //Agregamos la Clase de Mui para decir que el input no esta vacio y que suba el Texto del Label(Como cuando haces Focus)
} //Aqui termina la Funcion
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form>
  <legend>Contando Caracteres de Input</legend>
  <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
    <input type="text" required id="write" onKeyDown="kotoba()" onKeyUp="kotoba()" maxlength="30">
    <!--Agregamos los onKeyDown y onKeyUp para activar la Funcion cada vez que se escriba en el input-->
    <label>Contador</label>
  </div>
  <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
    <input type="text" id="result" readonly>
    <label>Resultado</label>
  </div>
</form>




Pero cual es el problema???

Esto asegura que la función kotoba maneje la actualización del contador, y la alerta se muestra cuando el campo pierde el foco y tiene menos de 30 caracteres.
function kotoba() {
  const len = $("#write").val().length;
  $("#result").val(len + " Caracteres").addClass('mui--is-not-empty');
}

$("#write").on('blur', function() {
  if (this.value.length > 0 && this.value.length < 30) alert("Faltan caracteres");
});


hola gracias por responder.. le agrego la linea pero ahora aparece el alert al ingresar el primer carecter y no deja pasar de alli

Lo he actualizado. No es facil hacerlo en 1 linea.

he intentado agregarle que en el alert me muestre la cantidad de caracteres restantes pero me sale en la Resta en famoso NAN llevo esto

ya lo logre usando esto  var total3 = parseFloat(total1) - parseFloat(total2);

Eso es facil calcular 30 - this.value.length son los caracteres restantes. No te funciono mi código?
